# C# PostMessage CTRL+Fx not working

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm trying to simulate the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> key press in a window, but it's not working as spected. When my program send the key stroke, it just ignore the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, so if it press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, the window gets only the <kbd>F3</kbd> key press, here are some screenshots of the events captured with Window Detective:

Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>manually:

[image]

And this one is my program pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> using PostMessage:
[image]

As you can see, they are exactly the same, so I have no idea what to do anymore. Here is the code I'm using:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, uint wParam, uint lParam);

const int VK_CONTROL = 0x11;
const uint VK_CONTROL_LUP = 0xC01D0001;
const uint VK_CONTROL_LDOWN = 0x1D0001;

const int VK_F3 = 0x72;
const uint F3_LDOWN = 0x3D0001;
const uint F3_LUP = 0xC03D0001;

const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;

//Modifier
PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, (uint)VK_CONTROL, VK_CONTROL_LDOWN);

//Key down
WinApi.PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, (uint)VK_F3, F3_LDOWN);
//key up
WinApi.PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, (uint)VK_F3, F3_LUP);

WinApi.PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, (uint)VK_CONTROL, VK_CONTROL_LUP);
```

After a few tests I added a delay of 10 seconds after the first PostMessage (holding <kbd>CTRL</kbd> down) and if I press an arrow key the window detect the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> pressed, but if I press any other key, like <kbd>F3</kbd>, it just ignore it.

There is any other way to send key strokes to unfocused windows besides the PostMessage I'm using? Or there is some secret behind it that it might be ignored for some programs?

Thanks

Comment: [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: [You can’t simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513). You are looking for [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) instead.

Comment: As I said, I need to send key strokes on unfocused windows, so SendKeys won't work, and we can simulate keyboard inputs with PostMessage.

Comment: No you can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage

Comment: So how to send keyboard inputs to a window that might not be in focus(on background)?

Comment: You can't.  Use UI Automation instead.  (Or, failing all else, move the target window to the foreground and give it the focus, then call SendKeys or the equivalent.)